# Flutter How to always hide keyboard when click on TextField but keep focus(Keep show cursor)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can't control keyboard show or hide, In my project I need to always hide keyboard but keep focused to display my custom keyboard(a widget).

**This is I want**

[image]

**And this is my problem**

[image]

Comment: import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');

Comment: @Kenneth Li 
`void initState() {
    focusNode.addListener(_changeFocus);
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
    super.initState();
  }`
it not work

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16863 might help

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer this way is use solution custom a EditableText and add
`SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide')` it work but wee can custom TextField and add this code in request keyboard ?

Comment: @quyenphongtranvuong Can you please let me know how did you get this functionality because I need the same thing.

Answer (score 92):

To hide keyboard and keep the cursor visible, set `readOnly` to `true` and `showCursor` to `true`.

```
TextFormField(
  showCursor: true,
  readOnly: true),
```

See [flutter/issues/#16863](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16863)

Comment: one thing to note is that when readOnly is true, you cannot use AutofillHints.

Answer (score 22):

FYI, TextInputType.none was introduced in [#83974](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/83974):

TextField(
keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
...
)

Comment: How can I enter text into input when TextInputType.none

Answer (score 9):

You can use custom focusNode

This prevents keyboard appearing only on first tap:

```
TextField(focusNode: FirstDisabledFocusNode(),)

class FirstDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool consumeKeyboardToken() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This prevents always:

```
TextField(focusNode: AlwaysDisabledFocusNode())

class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}
```

Comment: Thank your  answer @Defiant UA - In first way FirstDisabledFocusNode when you double tap on TextField keyboard still show 

In Second way I need show cursor. Have any way to disable keyboard still keep using TextField

Comment: Sorry, I don't know another solutions. And yes - as I've written - my first solution works only with first tap on `TextField`

Answer (score 3):

Insert `NoKeyboardEditableText` instead your `TextField`

```
class NoKeyboardEditableText extends EditableText {

  NoKeyboardEditableText({
    @required TextEditingController controller,
    TextStyle style = const TextStyle(),
    Color cursorColor = Colors.black,
    bool autofocus = false,
    Color selectionColor
  }):super(
      controller: controller,
      focusNode: NoKeyboardEditableTextFocusNode(),
      style: style,
      cursorColor: cursorColor,
      autofocus: autofocus,
      selectionColor: selectionColor,
      backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black
  );

  @override
  EditableTextState createState() {
    return NoKeyboardEditableTextState();
  }

}

class NoKeyboardEditableTextState extends EditableTextState {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget = super.build(context);
    return Container(
      decoration: UnderlineTabIndicator(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
      child: widget,
    );
  }

  @override
  void requestKeyboard() {
    super.requestKeyboard();
    //hide keyboard
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
  }
}

class NoKeyboardEditableTextFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool consumeKeyboardToken() {
    // prevents keyboard from showing on first focus
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get this way, but it don't have some property in TextField I need, ex: Move cursor to edit before word... Have any way to disable Keyboard of TextField when focus?

Comment: I think, for move cursor you can use `TextEditingController`. I don't know appropriate solution for `TextField`, but I'd recommended you to look in `EditableText` sources. In my example there are just few properties, but `EditableText` has quite a lot of them. So, maybe you can add all needed fields to you class, which extends `EditableText` and this'll be enough.

Answer (score 1):

try use `input_with_keyboard_control` package

It helped me solve my problem, of receiving the text from a barcode scanner, without showing the keyboard

Comment: link to the package?

Comment: this didn't help me. How did you do it, can you share with me?