# How to update Pin on keyboard press?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I update the PinInput Boxes with input from the on-screen keyboard? From what I understand, whenever there's a state change, the widget will be rebuild. Hence, from below, what I did was updating the text whenever the on-screen keyboard detects tap. Then since the state is  changed, I assumed it will rebuild all the widget which include the PinInput widget, and this is true since I tested the text whenever there's changes. I then did _pinPutController.text = text; to change the input of PinInput, however it is not working.

When I hardcode _pinPutController.text = '123', it works. So the problem is that it is not rebuilding. Am I understanding this correctly? How can I achieve what I wanted?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:numeric_keyboard/numeric_keyboard.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pin_put/pin_put.dart';

import '../../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../../size_config.dart';

class InputForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputFormState createState() => _InputFormState();
}

class _InputFormState extends State<InputForm> {
  String text = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        PinInput(text: text),
        NumericKeyboard(
            onKeyboardTap: (value) {
              setState(() {
                text += value;
              });
            },
            textColor: Colors.red,
            rightButtonFn: () {
              setState(() {
                text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
              });
            },
            rightIcon: Icon(
              Icons.backspace,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PinInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const PinInput({
    Key key,
    this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = getProportionateScreenHeight(60);
    final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
    final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _pinPutFocusNode.unfocus();
    print(text);
    _pinPutController.text = text;

    return PinPut(
      fieldsCount: 4,
      onSubmit: (String pin) => {},
      focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
      controller: _pinPutController,
      preFilledWidget: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Divider(
          color: kPrimaryColor,
          thickness: 2.5,
          indent: 7.5,
          endIndent: 7.5,
        ),
      ),
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: getProportionateScreenHeight(24),
      ),
      eachFieldPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
        getProportionateScreenHeight(10),
      ),
      eachFieldMargin: EdgeInsets.all(
        getProportionateScreenWidth(5),
      ),
      eachFieldHeight: size,
      eachFieldWidth: size,
      submittedFieldDecoration: boxDecoration(),
      selectedFieldDecoration: boxDecoration(),
      followingFieldDecoration: boxDecoration(),
      inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        counterText: '',
      ),
      withCursor: true,
      pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.scale,
      animationDuration: kAnimationDuration,
    );
  }

  BoxDecoration boxDecoration() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
        getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you recreate a new `TextEditingController` at each rebuild of your `PinInput` Widget. However, if you check the `PinPutState` of the [pinput package](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput), it keeps a reference to the first `TextEditingController` you provide in its `initState` method:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  _controller = widget.controller ?? TextEditingController();
  [...]
}
```

So, you have to keep the same `TextEditingController` all the way.

The easiest way to fix this would be to raise the `TextEditingController` to the State of `InputForm`. Instead of a `String text`, just use a Controller:

```dart
class InputForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputFormState createState() => _InputFormState();
}

class _InputFormState extends State<InputForm> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: '');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        PinInput(controller: _controller),
        NumericKeyboard(
          onKeyboardTap: (value) => _controller.text += value,
          textColor: Colors.red,
          rightButtonFn: () => _controller.text =
              _controller.text.substring(0, _controller.text.length - 1),
          rightIcon: Icon(Icons.backspace, color: Colors.red),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

*Note: Since you use a `TextEditingController` instead of a `String`, you can get rid of all your `setState` methods.*

[image]

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:numeric_keyboard/numeric_keyboard.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pin_put/pin_put.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: InputForm()),
    );
  }
}

class InputForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputFormState createState() => _InputFormState();
}

class _InputFormState extends State<InputForm> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: '');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        PinInput(controller: _controller),
        NumericKeyboard(
          onKeyboardTap: (value) => _controller.text += value,
          textColor: Colors.red,
          rightButtonFn: () => _controller.text =
              _controller.text.substring(0, _controller.text.length - 1),
          rightIcon: Icon(Icons.backspace, color: Colors.red),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PinInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const PinInput({
    Key key,
    this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = 60.0;
    final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _pinPutFocusNode.unfocus();

    return PinPut(
      fieldsCount: 4,
      onSubmit: (String pin) => {},
      focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
      controller: controller,
      preFilledWidget: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Divider(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          thickness: 2.5,
          indent: 7.5,
          endIndent: 7.5,
        ),
      ),
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 24,
      ),
      eachFieldPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
        10,
      ),
      eachFieldMargin: EdgeInsets.all(
        5,
      ),
      eachFieldHeight: size,
      eachFieldWidth: size,
      submittedFieldDecoration: boxDecoration(),
      selectedFieldDecoration: boxDecoration(),
      followingFieldDecoration: boxDecoration(),
      inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        counterText: '',
      ),
      withCursor: true,
      pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.scale,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
  }

  BoxDecoration boxDecoration() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
        10,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### UPDATE: How to hide the Keyboard...

...while keeping the focus blinking cursor

#### 1. disable the focus on your `PinPut` fields:

For this, I used a class described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234039):

```dart
class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}
```

...as the `focusNode` of the `PinPut`:

```dart
class PinInput extends StatelessWidget {
  [...]
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = 60.0;
    final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = AlwaysDisabledFocusNode();
    // _pinPutFocusNode.unfocus();

    return PinPut(
      [...]
      focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
      [...]
    );
  }
}
```

So, now, the `PinPut` never gets the focus. The Soft Keyboard is not shown but, hey!, we lost the blinking cursor!

No worries, we'll keep it always on programmatically.

### 2. Keep the blinking cursor always on

For this, though, we'll have to change the code of the [pinput package](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput).

Currently, in `PinPutState`, the blinking cursor is shown on the next field if `withCursor` is set to `true`  and the `PinPut` has the focus. Instead, we will always show the blinking cursor if `withCursor`is set to `true`:

```dart
if (widget.withCursor /* && _focusNode!.hasFocus */ && index == pin.length) {
  return _buildCursor();
}
```

Voilà! Does it work for you?

This has been mentioned on `PinPut` GitHub Issue Tracker [[ref](https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_PinPut/issues/50)] about disabling the device keyboard when using a custom keyboard.

Comment: Thank @Thierry for the clear and concise answer. Another question is that how can I disable the OS keyboard that comes up every-time there's focus? Autofocus should remain true, but just without the OS keyboard

Comment: I might have a solution for that.