# Flutter: How to implement on screen Numpad for multiple TextFormFields in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a custom Numpad widget in my Flutter app.

[image: Custom Numpad and textfields]

```
  class NumPadCheckout extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Function delete;
  final Function onSubmit;

  const NumPadCheckout({
    Key? key,
    required this.delete,
    required this.onSubmit,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "1",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "2",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "3",
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "4",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "5",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "6",
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "7",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "8",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "9",
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // this button is used to delete the last number
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "00",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            NumberButtonCheckout(
              number: "0",
              controller: controller,
            ),
            CustomKey(
              iconData: Icons.keyboard_backspace,
              onPressed: () => delete,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class NumberButtonCheckout extends StatelessWidget {
  final String number;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const NumberButtonCheckout({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.text += number.toString();
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            number.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomKey extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData iconData;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const CustomKey({
    Key? key,
    required this.iconData,
    required this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => onPressed,
        child:  Center(
          child: Icon(
              iconData
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to add this in a Screen and use it to input numbers to multiple TextFormFields I have on the same screen. Each TextFormField should have its own TextEditingControllers.And need to clear data when the backspace is in the numpad as well. How can I do this in Flutter?

Comment: you can use default numpad of phone's system using `TextEdittingController` with option `TextInputType.number`

Comment: It's not the requirement I have. Need to have an on screen numpad.

Comment: weird requirement that takes a lot of efforts :v Good luck to u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 textfields, you will need a controller for **each** **TextField** (2 controllers for both textfields).
You can create a **3rd controller** to know which textfield is currently being used.

You could do something like this:

```
  final TextEditingController _cashAmountController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _creditAmountController = TextEditingController();
  late TextEditingController _activeController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _activeController = _cashAmountController;
  }
```

The **3rd controller** is what you would pass to your **NumPadCheckout** so that when **another TextField** is selected, it gets the **right controller** for the newly selected TextField.

Now you need to change the value of the 3rd controller depending on which TextField is selected. **TextField** has an **onTap** property which you can use to set your **3rd controller** to the controller for that **TextField**.

In your build method, you could have this:

```
Column(
      children: [
        //cash amount textfield
        TextField(
          onTap: () {
            //change the active controller when the textfield is tapped on (focused)
            _activeController = _cashAmountController;
          },
        ),

        //credit amount textfield
        TextField(
          onTap: () {
            //change the active controller when the textfield is tapped on (focused)
            _activeController = _creditAmountController;
          },
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: NumPadCheckout(
            controller: _activeController,
            delete: onDelete,
            submit: onSubmit,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

You could also use FocusNode as suggested by [Nguyen Family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77214962/16820911) but remember to set the keyboardType of your TextField to TextInputType.none

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, with 2 (or more) text fields, we need 2 `TextEdittingController`. As your requirements, this Numpad will be used by both 2 text fields. So the question is: **How do we know which text field is being typed?**

Oh, problem is clearer now. I suggest you use 2 [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html), which are called `cashFocusNode` &  `creditFocusNode` and attach them into 2 `TextEdittingController` (and don't forget to dispose).

With `NumberButtonCheckout`, you could code its `onPressed` function like this:

```
  NumberButtonCheckout(
    onPressed: () => onPressedNumber(number);
  )
```

...

```
  void onPressedNumber(String number) {
    if (cashFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      cashTextEdittingController.text += number;
    } else if (creditFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      creditTextEdittingController.text += number;
    } else {
      // do nothing if no text field is being typed
    }
  }
```

Do the same thing `CustomKey` with backspace.

**Edit:** Oh right, I almost forgot. If we using focus node, the phone's keyboard will show up. It leads us to this post: [Flutter How to always hide keyboard when click on TextField but keep focus(Keep show cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234039/flutter-how-to-always-hide-keyboard-when-click-on-textfield-but-keep-focuskeep)